# Eclipse bold font rendering very different among Linux and Windows

Tags: eclipse, linux-mint

Why all bold fonts rendering in eclipse are very different between Linux and Windows ?

Look at the sample for "Source Code Pro" font:
[image]

I tested others fonts, and all them in the Linux rendering is a little bit more bold, and the bold version of the font seems to be another font, is very different.

There are ways to minimize this effect ?

**EDIT:** Hardware and virtualization

Both are running on the same monitor. Windows on the bare-metal, Linux inside Virtualbox (Windows is the host OS).

Answer (score 3):

The pixel density of a typical computer screen is way too low to display small shapes such as font glyphs accurately (too many rounding errors).

Thus, every major text stack (which are complex enough there is about one by operating system no more) has to decide whether rounding up or down glyph dimensions when they don't neatly fit in exact pixel multiples (fitting glyphs to the pixel grid, aka "grid-fitting"), how much it is ready to distort glyph shapes in the process (pixelisation, moving some bits in one dimension and others in another), whether it smooths edges using greyscale pixels or even color pixel ("subpixel" smoothing that also produces color fringing), etc.

And, do that consistently. It does not help if you produce a very clear glyph but it loses alignment with other glyphs of the same font. It does not help if consecutive sizes of the font are not linear, because some have been rounded up and others down. It does not help if your rendering algorithm changes or moves consecutive iterations of the same glyph differently, series of iiiiiii or lllll may be uncommon but series or 11111111 aren't in spreadsheets for example.

Bold is even harder than regular text because fonts have converged to about one or two pixel widths for most glyph stems on a typical screen at typical sizes, but users expect bold to be a little fatter without being twice as fat.

Not two text stacks make the same compromises, and Windows default rendering is especially extreme, trying to get sharp thin shapes at the expense of pretty much every other factor. Apple and Adobe rendering is usually smoother (but "blurrier") and Linux is somewhere in-between, with Adobe contributing heavily to Linux rendering stack in recent years.

And no one has ever been able to prove one rendering style is better than the others. The only consistent factor is what the user is accustomed to, expose a user to one style of rendering for a few months he will hate all others, it does not matter which rendering he is exposed to and it can be changed by forcing him to use another rendering a few months. Probably due to the way the brain shape recognition processes self-train and optimize towards what they see most often. The more one user is exposed to a particular font and text rendering the more he will find this particular combination pleasant and easy to read.

Linux being eminently tweakable you can force its rendering stack to behave more like Windows. It will be more pleasant for you if you're used to Windows rendering. It will be less pleasant for anyone that does not spend his life in Windows. Typically, change the hinting aggressiveness in fontconfig, the smoothing from grayscale to rgbA (that *will* produce color fringing). Or even use a patched version like infinality (quite extreme, and not really necessary, changing fontconfig settings is usually enough). Something like gnome-tweak-tool can help you to it graphically, and eclipse inherits gtk settings via SWT.

Or, use larger text, or buy a high-density (highdpi) screen. The smaller pixels are compared to glyph elements the less grid-fitting rounding effects you get, regardless of the text stack in use. With high-enough pixel density you get the "ideal" glyph shapes and weights, the same as on a good laser printer.

Of course that supposes the operating system is able to drive the high-dpi screen. Linux should be getting there but Windows is still firmly stuck in 96dpi land last time I checked.

Lastly, if you work in a virtual environment, the VM layer may hide some hardware characteristics to the virtualized software. So it has less chances to accurately detect screen characteristics and tune its rendering accordingly.